# Core Data does not delete the object

Tags: swift, core-data

I just met a strange issue with deletion of objects from Core Data.
My code looks like:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Favorites")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectID == %ld", object.id)

    do {
        let favoriteObject = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Favorites]

        if favoriteObject > 0 {
            // Already exist. Delete
            do {
                context.delete(favoriteObject[0])
                try context.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Also I want to mention that `Favorites` has One-to-One relationship with `Objects`. After executing my deletion code it nullifies the relation but the record stays there in the list of Database. It's really strange thing. What goes wrong and how can I fix that?

After deletion the record in DB looks like:

```
`ObjectID` = `0`
`object`: `NULL`(the foreign key)
```

Comment: `stays there in the list of Database.`: What does that mean? Did you fetch again and an object with the same objectID came up again?

Comment: @Purpose no, I'm opening the `sqlite` file and see records there

Comment: CoreData is using `sqlite`, but how do you know that what you see is not how CoreData simply does its deletes? If you don't fetch again I don't see how you would see whether an object is deleted or not. You could refetch the object from the store by objectID to test if it throws or not.

Comment: @Purpose I know what happens when Core Data deletes the record. It disappears from the sqlite file also. Also it fetches it.

Comment: So you refetched AFTER you deleted yes no?

Comment: @Purpose yes, I do

Comment: And the successfully refetched has the EXACT SAME ObjectID as the object you just deleted?

Comment: @Purpose yes. It nullifies only the relationship

Comment: And you do the refetch in the EXACT SAME context you have deleted the object before?

Comment: You can try [object(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506197-object) to see whether it throws an Error or [the non-throwing version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506686-existingobject). If the above is true and it does not throw an error then I don't know any further.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your predicate works.
1) You are getting an array of 'favoreteObject' and trying to delete the first one...
2) try, 'if favoirteObject.count > 0'
3) try ' context.delete out of the 'do' block

```
    if favoriteObject.count > 0 {
        // Already exist. Delete

        context.delete(favoriteObject[0])

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```